# What parts of Civ 5 scale with map size?

Tags: civilization-5

Which parts of the game in Civ5 do (also) scale with map size? (As opposed to difficulty or game pace)

- Necessary production?
- Culture Border expansion?
- Required scientific output?
- City growth rate?
- Unit mechanics?
- ... ?
- (I am less interested in the score scaling that is mentioned in the manual.)

The only definite answer I have off the top of my head is: *number of opponents* :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Aspects that scale with map size**

- Technology costs

  - 100% at duel, tiny and small
  - 110% at standard
  - 120% at large
- Score scaling details in [this answer from me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/how-is-the-score-calculated-in-civilization-5/9105#9105)

**Aspects that don't scale with map size**

- Production costs
- Social policy costs
- Border expansion culture costs
- city growth

Comment: You may as well name that 2nd list "Aspects that scale with game speed". Between the two, I think you've addressed every scaling aspect of Civ.