# Why would spending money on a tile lower my score?

Tags: civilization-5

I was playing Civilization 5 as the Arabian empire, and one of my warriors found some Ruins and earned me about 70 coins. My score was 14 at the time, and didn't go up due to the increased amount of money. I spent them on a tile nearby my city, and my score went from 14 to 13. Could someone please explain? How does money effect score, and number of tiles not?

Comment: Related: [How is score calculated in Civilization 5?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/how-is-the-score-calculated-in-civilization-5) Based on what they found in that question, I don't actually see how this is possible, and should actually have been the reverse. I wonder if there's something else going on.

Comment: I agree, there must be another factor effecting my score that I did not notice. I'm playing on a large map as well, so I don't believe tiles effect your score at all, either.

Comment: Yah, this sounds like a bug, you should've gone from 14 to 15.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried replicating this, with exact same conditions (map size, civ ect) but unless you play with some 3rd party mods, I will have to call this one a bug.

There was one version where the point system calculation was completely off. Can't remember which one.

Alternatively, someone might have messed with your GlobalDefines.xml, or if you were playing multiplayer, the game maker might have been messing with his GlobalDefines.xml. (You could do this in the early games and have messed up cheating / point calculation.)

But unless you get beaten militantly, it's rather hard to drop in score.