# Does a lake count as a coast?

Tags: civilization-5

I have a city built on the shore of a large lake. Does that count as if the city is "on a coast", for the sake of things like buildings that I can build? Notice that if I hover over the water tile it distinctively says "lake" and not "coast".

For example, can I build a lighthouse on a city situated on the shores of a lake?

Comment: Apparently your lake wasn't large enough. As happens to be shown in my screenshot [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/general-strategies-build-order-in-civilization-5/8771#8771), *very large* lakes do count as oceans (compare the mini map and the cursor tooltip).

Comment: @deceze I'm talking about lake as a technical tile type, not as a body of water surrounded by land. In other words, I knew the solution for this question if the tile type is coast, even if the sea itself is inland; but I didn't know it for lakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't build any coast-specific buildings like lighthouse or harbor in a city near a lake. I just tried it on a Lake-type map.

There is the Garden as a lake (or river)-specific improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Lakes count like rivers, so it irrigates tiles. You can't put any ocean specific stuff there.