# What tips would you give beginners at Civilization 4?

Tags: civilization-4

Similar to [General strategies/build order in Civilization 5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8769/general-strategies-build-order-in-civilization-5), I'd like some help getting started at Civilization 4. I can't go much beyond the easiest level without getting another civilization declare war on me (and defeat me!).

So - how should a beginner succeed at Civ4 (and specifically avoid or win wars)?

Comment: You should note that the crux of that accepted answer on that question is "it depends." There was no direct strategy or build order given. There are far too many variables to be able to write a comprehensive walkthrough/strategy guide for even a single Civilization in a Civ game. The tips that deceze gave are very good and would apply to both games.

Comment: This question is too open-ended, bad-subjective (list of tips), and unlike the Civ5 question, it hasn't received an excellent answer to redeem it. Closing.

Comment: @badp - how *can* it receive an excellent answer if you close it?

Comment: I know it hasn't, and I know the subpar answer you received satisfies you (you accepted the answer today at 0613 UTC). I can't foresee the future... if somebody wants to take a quality stab at this after just @-reply me.

Comment: Here's a great link: http://www.civfanatics.com/files/Civ%20IV%20Basic%20Strategy%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best source of information for Civilization is the CivFanatics Forums.

This is an excellent pdf covering most of the topics you need to know about [Sisiutil's Strategy Guide for Beginners](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=165632)

For further information you can check out the subforum for strategy articles:
[Strategy Articles](http://forums.civfanatics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=156)

Comment: Mind including the gist of the content so that, if (or rather, when) the links break, this answer is still somewhat useful?

Comment: @fail Not sure how well he'd be able to sum up all the points in the PDF. It's 46 pages long.